# Need a generic way to create SEO friendly URL

Tags: seo, htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost, url-shorteners

I have searched a lot and implemented many many Regular Expression in my .htaccess file but can not succeed.  **How do I find a generic way that make my URL SEO friendly?**

Currently this is in my .htaccess file:

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

What I need to do is that I have a URL like this:

```
   http://localhost/abc/index.php?page=boats_for_sale
```

I need to change it to

```
  http://localhost/abc/boats_for_sale
```

Similarly, I want to hide all query strings in my URL.  How would I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ user.php?username=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ user.php?username=$1
```

for detail follow this [link](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html)